# Parentnode working different in IE11

Tags: javascript

I have the below statement in my code. In IE11, double quotes is getting added in this variable"a" but in IE8, no quotes is getting appended. The unwanted double quotes is causing exception. Any inputs ?

```
var a = thisObject.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.cells[1].innerHTML;
```

Comment: What quotes are you talking about?

Comment: double quotes "- <div id="unmaskCopyMenu_0"..../> in IE11 but in IE 8 <div id=unmaskCopyMenu_0..../>

Comment: There is nothing you can do to change that. That is how the browser works. Plenty of questions on here on the same topic.

Comment: Oh ok... then i will change the code to ignore the quotes in IE11... i think that is only workarund we are left with then. Please let me know your thoughts. thanks.